# mongodump in mongodb container

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, doctrine, mongodump

I'm using 2 docker containers: one for my PHP application and one for MongoDb. PHP application writes data into MongoDb container using Doctrine, without any problem, but when I want to make a backup inside of PHP application container by running:

```
$mongodump --host mongo --port 27017
```

it creates the "dump/product" folder but it is empty.

Also if I go inside of MongoDb container, I can see the database and the right data in collections, but if I try to connect to MongoDb inside of php application container with:

```
$mongo --host mongo --port 27017
```

it connects, it shows the database, but it has no collection.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you include the connection string that you use for Doctrine?

Comment: I found the reason. On my Php application container I have MongoDb 2.4 and on my MongoDb container I have MongoDb 3.2 (pulling the latest mongo image). After I downgrade the Mongo version on my Mongo container, everything is fine now. Probably MongoDb shell version 3.2 is incompatible with earlier versions of mongod. Thank you for trying to help me. :)